what is this part/component in this circuit schematic?
I have a circuit schematic (this is just a part of it):

I am trying to find what those little circles above and below the speaker are. I dont think they are part of the speaker itself, as there is more of them elsewhere in the circuit without any speakers attached.
My best guess would be they are some kind of connection pins, but i couldnt find anything.

Probably tie points, terminals, headers/pins, loose wires, etc.
The diagonal line probably imitates something like a cross-screw, or clip, as you would have in a screw terminal, terminal strip, Fahnestock clip, etc.  The diagram seems old, and these traditions probably date back to the 40s or thereabouts; they may also be relatively current, check ANSI schematic standards for ideas.
The purpose of indicating them on the schematic, might be for assemblers or repairpersons looking for where (or when) to attach the speaker leads (whether by connectors or soldered), or to populate BOM items (more in the post-CAD era, where automatic BOM generation is available; the symbols ought to have designators, then, too).
If you don't have a library symbol to use, drawing it anew is probably the intended route (perhaps making your own library as well).

They indicate there could be some kind of connector or terminal instead of the speaker being fixed and undetachable.

thanks for your help, i appreciate it. Do you know what they are called? I am trying to redraw the schematic in fusion 360

@VincentCerowski It would probably help if you have a datasheet to the speaker. Is it a MEMS thing?

@Lundin i dont have anything. I have literally just been given a schematic and told to make a PCB out of it in fusion, nothing else provided.
